# How convert a table formatted string to a json response in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am looking to convert a table formatted string which is a newman response to json format. Below is the string

```
 ┌─────────────────────────┬────────────────────┬───────────────────┐
 │                         │           executed │            failed │
 ├─────────────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
 │              iterations │                  1 │                 0 │
 ├─────────────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
 │                requests │                 30 │                 0 │
 ├─────────────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
 │            test-scripts │                 60 │                 0 │
 ├─────────────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
 │      prerequest-scripts │                 38 │                 0 │
 ├─────────────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
 │              assertions │                 56 │                 0 │
 ├─────────────────────────┴────────────────────┴───────────────────┤
 │ total run duration: 8.9s                                         │
 ├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
 │ total data received: 8.19kB (approx)                             │
 ├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
 │ average response time: 267ms                                     │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I am trying to convert the above to a json response as below

```
{
     "iterations": {
            "executed" : 1,
            "failed" : 0
            },
     "requests":{
            "executed" : 30,
            "failed" : 0
        },
     "test-scripts":{
            "executed" : 60,
            "failed" : 0
        },
    "prerequest-scripts":{
            "executed" : 38,
            "failed" : 0
        },
    "assertions":{
            "executed" : 60,
            "failed" : 0
        },
     "total run duration": "8.9s"    
     "total data received": "8.19kB (approx)"          
     "average response time": "267ms"  
}
```

Can someone help me on this please.

Comment: Seems like not generating the table in the first place would be ideal. Can you write a [custom reporter](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/newman-custom-reporters/) to generate the JSON in the first place?

Comment: Awk command resolved this issue

Answer (score 1):

Given that *exact* string:

```
$ echo "$s"
┌─────────────────────────┬────────────────────┬───────────────────┐
│                         │           executed │            failed │
├─────────────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│              iterations │                  1 │                 0 │
├─────────────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│                requests │                 30 │                 0 │
├─────────────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│            test-scripts │                 60 │                 0 │
├─────────────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│      prerequest-scripts │                 38 │                 0 │
├─────────────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│              assertions │                 56 │                 0 │
├─────────────────────────┴────────────────────┴───────────────────┤
│ total run duration: 8.9s                                         │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ total data received: 8.19kB (approx)                             │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ average response time: 267ms                                     │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

You can use this ruby:

```
echo "$s" | ruby -r json -e 's=$<.read
d={}
s.scan(/^\W*([a-zA-Z\-]+)\W*(\d+)\W*(\d+)/).
    map{|k,e,f| {"#{k}":{"executed":e, "failed":f}} }.
    each{|h| d.merge!(h) }

s.scan(/^(?=.*:)[ \t]*│[ \t]*([^:]*):[ \t]*(.*?)(?:[ \t]{2,}|│)/).
    map{|k,v| {"#{k}":v}}.
    each{|h| d.merge!(h) }

puts JSON.pretty_generate(d)'
```

Prints:

```
{
  "iterations": {
    "executed": "1",
    "failed": "0"
  },
  "requests": {
    "executed": "30",
    "failed": "0"
  },
  "test-scripts": {
    "executed": "60",
    "failed": "0"
  },
  "prerequest-scripts": {
    "executed": "38",
    "failed": "0"
  },
  "assertions": {
    "executed": "56",
    "failed": "0"
  },
  "total run duration": "8.9s",
  "total data received": "8.19kB (approx)",
  "average response time": "267ms"
}
```